# What is the relation between truth values and the integers $0$ and $1$?

Tags: logic

Consider a formula such as $a = b$. In classic propositional logic, one would say that formula carries a truth value, i.e., it is either $\sf TRUE$ or $\sf FALSE$. These truth values are sometimes associated with the integers $1$ (for $\sf TRUE$) and $0$ (for $\sf FALSE$). However, from my understanding, this association is purely conventional, i.e., it wouldn't make a difference if $1$ stood for $\sf FALSE$ and $0$ for $ \sf TRUE$ (or $-20$ for $\sf TRUE$ and $13$ for $\sf FALSE$).

However, I just found out that it is possible to do basic arithmetic operations on truth values, which are based upon the premise that $\sf TRUE$ equals $1$ and $\sf FALSE$ equals $0$. For example, $\sf TRUE + TRUE$ comes out as $2$. This would seem dubious if the relation between truth values and $0$ and $1$ is purely arbitary. So is there some deeper connection between truth values and $0$ and $1$? Or should we say that doing arithmetic with truth values is in principle nonsensical?

Comment: Here, rather than $1+1=2$ you should be thinking $1\oplus 1 = 1$... we aren't using addition as normally defined for the natural numbers, but rather something which corresponds to the logical `OR` operator which works such that $0\oplus 0 = 0$ while $1\oplus 0 = 0\oplus 1 = 1\oplus 1 = 1$

Comment: [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) is not the same as arithmetic on the field of real numbers.  But it is similar to arithmetic on [the field with two elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)) $\mathbf F_2$

Comment: "*Should we say that doing arithmetic with truth values is in principle nonsensical?*"  Certainly not.  You can apply however much meaning you want to whatever you want.  You can define rules for arithmetic however you want as well.  Remember... the problems we want to solve come first, and the definitions and rules we follow are written in such a way so as to be *useful* for the problems we wanted to solve.  It is clear that interpreting and manipulating these things with these rules of arithmetic is in fact useful (*if nothing else to organize thoughts*)

Comment: Thanks, these comments are really helpful. Boolean arithmetic is clearly not reliant on which integers are assigned to the truth values. What threw me off is that when you add TRUE and TRUE in any programming language the outcome is 2 rather than 1. From your comments it seems that that's a relatively odd outcome given that the integer assignment is arbitary.

Comment: No "deep" reasons at all to represent TRUE with $1$ and FALSE with $0$. Only an historical one, starting with George Boole's [Algebra of Logic (1847)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847) where $1$ stands for the *universe* in the class interpretation and for "all conceivable cases or circumstances" in the propositional interpretation. Thus, "minus" represents complement and negation i.e. $1-x$ is the complement of class $x$ as well as the "cases" where prop $x$ is false.

Comment: @pituitary_plea in terms of programming languages... Javascript for instance, zero (*written as $0$ or $0.0$*) is a "falsey" value while any other int or float is considered "truthy"... so in most cases you would have `a+b` will have the same truthiness as `a||b`.  There are exceptions though... in particular when $a=-b$... so correctly using `||` rather than `+` is strongly recommended.

Comment: As for why `true + true` might evaluate to $2$ in programming languages... the language very probably has smart type-casting.  Stricter typed languages like Java refuse to allow you to add two booleans.  A language like Javascript or Python however will see that you tried to add booleans... and knowing that actual *addition* only makes sense for actual *numbers*, it converts the booleans to numbers in the logical way and *then* performs the arithmetic, similar to how `"1"+0` results in `"10"` with the $0$ there being typecast to string so that the string concatenation makes sense.